# Load customer Quote Error in magento 2.1 EE

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, quote

Once the customer is logged in or creating account, `Load Customer Quote` **Error** is getting.

Can you please help me solve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Find how many quotes are there for that customer, and disable all quote in database by update query, once this is done try to login im sure issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear cache and cookies: Clear your browser cache and cookies and check if the issue is resolved. If not, try clearing the Magento cache by going to System > Cache Management in the admin panel and clicking on "Flush Magento Cache".
2. Reindex the website: Go to System > Index Management in the admin panel and select "Select All" in the grid, then choose "Reindex" from the actions dropdown and click "Submit". This may help resolve any indexing issues that could be causing the error.
3. Check third-party extensions: Disable any third-party extensions that you have installed one by one, to see if they are causing the issue. To disable an extension, go to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced in the admin panel, then find the extension in the list and change its status to "Disabled".
4. Check the database: The issue could be caused by a problem with the database. You can try running the following SQL query in your Magento database:

SELECT * FROM `quote` WHERE `customer_id` = <customer_id>

Replace <customer_id> with the ID of the affected customer. If this query returns any errors or empty results, then it indicates an issue with the customer quote in the database.

5. Check the customer session: The issue could be related to the customer session. You can try clearing the customer session by deleting the mage-cache-sessid cookie in your browser, or by deleting the session and cache folders in the var directory of your Magento installation.